# Why is this type not inferred by compiler?

Tags: scala

This code returns error :

```
  case class Leaf1[A](value: A)
  case class Branch1[A](left: Leaf1[A], right: Leaf1[A])

  def size1[A](t: Leaf1[A]): Int = t match {
    case Leaf1(_) => 1
    case Branch1(l, r) => 1 + size1(l) + size1(r)
  }

Multiple markers at this line - not found: value l - constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : 
 trees.Branch1[A(in class Branch1)] required: trees.Leaf1[A(in method size1)]
```

Why cannot `l` be inferred to be of type Leaf1 ?

If instead I use :

```
    sealed trait Tree[A]
  case class Leaf1[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
  case class Branch1[A](left: Leaf1[A], right: Leaf1[A]) extends Tree[A]

  def size1[A](t: Tree[A]): Int = t match {
    case Leaf1(_) => 1
    case Branch1(l, r) => 1 + size1(l) + size1(r)
  }                                               //> size1: [A](t: trees.Tree[A])Int
```

Then it compiles.

Since Leaf and Branch share a common parent object and are thus of the same type allow the Scala compiler to infer the type ?

Comment: This question is not about type inference; all of your code uses explicit types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not the `l` itself. On your first example, you're specifying that `t` is of type `Leaf1[A]`, and then trying to match it to a `Branch1[A]`, which is impossible, since it's not a subclass of `Leaf1` .
That's what the compiler complains about :

```
found:  trees.Branch1[A(in class Branch1)] required: trees.Leaf1[A(in method size1)]
```